# How to calculate the normal modes from a given potential?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, normal-modes

I have a potential of the form:
$U=\frac{1}{2}\omega_{0}^{2}(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2})-\alpha x_{1}x_{2}$

How can I find the normal modes of this potencial? Should I expect solutions of harmonic oscilator for $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$? Are those solutions of the form $x=Ae^{i\omega t}$ or are they like $Acos(\omega t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are solutions of the form $x_{1}=A_{1}e^{i\omega t}$ and $x_{2}=A_{2}e^{i\omega t}$ with a connection between $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$. For example, in your case the potential can be written as

$$U=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\omega_{0}^{2}-\alpha\right)\left(\dfrac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\omega_{0}^{2}+\alpha\right)\left(\dfrac{x_{1}-x_{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}$$

This means it is more natural to work with coordinates $y_{\pm}=\dfrac{x_{1}\pm x_{2}}{\sqrt{2}}$, and then the solution is simple - just two decoupled harmonic oscillators

$$y_{\pm}=y_{\pm}^{0}e^{i\omega_{\pm}t}$$

with $\omega_{\pm}^{2}=\omega_{0}^{2}\mp\alpha$. For simplicity let us assume $y_{-}^{0}=0$. Thus in the old coordinates

$$x_{1}=x_{2}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y_{+}^{0}e^{i\omega_{+}t}$$

In the other case $y_{+}^{0}=0$ you get

$$x_{1}=-x_{2}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y_{-}^{0}e^{i\omega_{+}t}$$

You can see that $A_{1}=\pm A_{2}$ respectively.